# How to skip over indentation whitespace with horizontal motion?

Tags: indentation, cursor-motions, whitespace

I have a file that uses 4-space indentation. By default, when I move horizontally, Vim moves over those spaces one by one.

How can I configure Vim so that it moves 4 spaces horizontally when moving over indentation whitespace?

Comment: I asked this question on SO last year: [How can I get the same behaviour navigating tabs if I use expandtab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27525238/660921), but never really got a satisfactory answer other than "use `w` or `^` to skip the indentation".

Comment: Use `noexpandtab`, configure 4-space tabs, and `:retab`. At the end, if you must, re-enable `expandtab` and `:retab` again.

Comment: I think all possible situations where one would *need* to move by `sw` are covered by other vim commands. For example, if one would need to move one indent level back and start inserting code there, we could instead de-indent first with `<<` and then press `I` to insert in the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can add the following functions to your `.vimrc`. They compare the current position of the cursor to the position of the first character and if necessary they skip the non printed characters before the first non blank one.

```
function! MyLMotion()
    let cursorPosition=getpos(".")
    normal ^
    let firstChar=getpos(".")

    if cursorPosition[2] < firstChar[2]
        normal ^
    else
        call setpos('.', cursorPosition)
        normal! l
    endif
endfunction
```

This one goes on the right: if the cursor is before the first non blank character, then we use `normal ^` to skip the whitespaces. If we are already on the line we use `normal! l` to move on the right. Note the use of `!`which allows to use the original `l` motion even if we remap the key (this will be necessary otherwise we create a recursive function).

```
function! MyHMotion()
    let cursorPosition=getpos(".")
    normal ^
    let firstChar=getpos(".")

    if cursorPosition[2] <= firstChar[2]
        normal 0
    else
        call setpos('.', cursorPosition)
        normal! h
    endif
endfunction
```

This one goes on the left, this time if the cursor is on the first non blank character we use `normal 0` to go on the beginning of the line and skip the white spaces.

You then have to create these mappings:

```
nnoremap <silent> h :call MyHMotion()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> l :call MyLMotion()<CR>
```

*Note the use of silent to prevent the messages `call MyXMotion` to be output in the status line each time you press `h` or `l`*

And you can use your `h` and `l` keyslike before but they'll skip the unwanted space at the beginning of your line.

Note that the advantage of this solution is that the functions should work whatever your configuration is (tabs of whitespaces).

Comment: Added this to my .vimrc. To me, this solves the problem the OP describes. It is also a nice&simple example of several vim scripting techniques. I'm keeping this :)

Comment: @AlexStragies: I'm glad you keep it! :)